# Custom underlining a tag in css

Tags: html, css

I have a div inside which there is a header and I want to underline the header such that the underline covers approx 80% of the div, with 10% indent on both sides. Also, I want the underline to be some pixels below the header. I am trying this

---

*In the html part*

```
<div id="divname">
     <h2>HEADER</h2>
</div>
```

---

---

*In the css part*

```
#divname h2 {
text-align: center;
font-family:arial,sans-serif;
text-decoration:underline;
}
```

---

but here the header is directly underlined with no height gap and also the underline has same width as the header data. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

set a border to the h2 element, and set its width to 80%; `margin:auto;` is used to center it

```
#divname h2{
    width:80%;
    margin:auto;
    display:block;
    border-bottom:1px solid gray;
}
```

here is a jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/bxKZ3/

Comment: Just to expand on this, if you want the underline to be further away from the text you can just add padding-bottom to the h2 :)

Comment: @SteveDay : Yeap, added on the jsfiddle :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can stylize the underline with CSS, but theres another way round:

Take a look at this [jSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zanjr/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="divname">
    <h2>HEADER</h2>
    <div class="underline"></div>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
#divname h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family:arial,sans-serif;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
.underline{
    height:1px;
    background:#000;
    margin:0px 10px;
}
```

Obviously, the `background:#000;` will change the underline color. Changing the `margin:0px 10px;` will decide how much space is on either side of the underline (I believe this was one of your requirements).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Border-bottom is generally better to fake an underline rather than creating a div (markup) just for style

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without extra markup if you use the before/after pseudo elements:

http://jsfiddle.net/bxKZ3/1/

```
h2{
    text-align: center;
    background:#eee; 
}
h2:after{
    border-bottom:1px solid gray;
    display: block;
    margin: 1em 10% 0 10%;
    content: " ";
}

<h2>bonjour</h2>
```